# How to filter objects in admin?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

> How i can filter objects that are shown in wagtail admin page of each
>   model?
>   In django this problem can be solved by overriding Admin class of model, in wagtail i dont know how it is possibile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about non-page objects, you have two options to expose them in the admin interface: [snippets](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/editor_manual/documents_images_snippets/snippets.html) and [ModelAdmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html).

The later is very similar to Django's ModelAdmin (but *is not the same*) and you should be able to overwrite `get_queryset` to filter the objects like you are used to with Django.

For example, after setting up the [ModelAdmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) app correctly, you can do something like this:

```
# models.py
class Person(django.db.models.Model):
  type = django.db.models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('student', 'Student'), ('teacher', 'Teacher')))
  # ...

# wagtail_hooks.py
class StudentAdmin(wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options.ModelAdmin):
  model = my_app.models.Person

  def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(type='student')

wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options.modeladmin_register(MyPageModelAdmin)
```